# iOS Custom Tab bar event in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to get a working "dialog" box for my app. I am not really sure what to do to accomplish this. I am looking to do something like how Instagram does it. When the user goes to create a post, the Add icon presents the user with a full screen page to add an image. Similarly I want to do just about the same.

However, I want it to send to a storyboard that I have made for the form I have created. When the user hits cancel or submit it sends them back to the original page that they were on. What is the best way to achieve something like this?

Comment: You are asking a very broad question, which is not actually related to tab bar events. What you are actually trying to do is use a button to present (segue to) a modal. You should start by looking that up.

Comment: What does this have to do with a custom tab bar event?

Comment: well if you are willing to invest, you can consider taking this course https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course/Instagram-Firebase. In one of the episodes, it teaches you how to do the "create post" feature like in Instagram.

Comment: @rmaddy Well just like the previous comment I am looking to have the Tabbar to pull up a storyboard in a modal view. I tried searching around there isn't anything I can find that really targets what I am doing.